# Sending an email wont auto populate subject

Tags: android, email

I am a bit confused as to why this will not work.

```
Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ "RJRandolph16@gmail.com" } );

                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, new String[]{"Rob Won"} );
                //emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, new String[]{"Testing 1 2 3" +
                //      "                                                               Testing 1 2 3"} );
                emailIntent.setType("text/plain");


                Activity.this.startActivity(emailIntent);
                }               }
        });
```

I am using my device as my emulator, using version 2.2. Every time I enter either the "Email" client or "Gmail" client this will not populate the subject line of the email. If this were to work I am hoping that the same logic would apply to auto filling the message as well right?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to set the subject as a string array, this is what worked for me, see if it works for you:

```
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Content of the email body");
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email Subject");
 emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
```

Comment: It did work for the subject. But the reason I was using the String[] was to allow me to add to it. If an item list had 1 or 3 items in it I would need to send 1 item or 3 items and need to manipulate the string accordingly.

Comment: Well, couldn't you combine the string array and make it into a single string for the subject? Or use a StringBuilder to build your subject. The EXTRA_SUBJECT is an intent extra for a string, as described by the Android Developer website: A constant string holding the desired subject line of a message.